# andy emulator error the operation was canceled

Tags: android-emulator, emulation

i install andy andriod emulator after opening i have error the operation was cancelled (10) and after click [ok] andy close Automatically.

[image: Screnshot]

Please help for fix it.

my graphic card update to last version

Comment: I got the same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I disabled hyper-v and it worked.

From an elevated command prompt:

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
```

Answer (score 3):

I was having this same issue.  As per Nauman, I checked and found hyper-V was enabled in Windows 10 itself - but I wanted to take advantage of my AMD Threadripper's CPU virtualization extensions.

So then I found out in UEFI-BIOS, it got disabled when I updated the UEFI Firmware on my motherboard.  (I'd previously enabled it for something else.)

I re-enabled SVM, under CPU Configuration on Asus Zenith Extreme, and low-and-behold Andy FINALLY started working! =)

Comment: it work to me, thank you very much, i just update bios and that disbaled my SVM option, that why it not working

Comment: Same for HP. Enabling virtualization technology (under System configuration) in BIOS helps.

Answer (score 2):

I had my hyper-v enabled which was causing issue. I [disabled it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xoB0iYipVx0) and it worked!